# How do I make certain menu items visible to certain roles?

Tags: drupal-7

In /drupal/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu, I have some links that I only want displayed for user's that have a specific permission.

How would I go about this?

In my module, I have

```
...

$items['resume/joblist'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'ac_resume_job_list',
  'access arguments' => array('view joblist'),
  'title' => 'Job List',
  'description' => 'Job List',
);

...

function ac_resume_permission()
{
  return array("view joblist" => array("title" => "View Job List"));
}
```

When I go to "resume/joblist" under a user without the permission, I get the "Access Denied" as expected, however the link is still displayed. 
[image]

Comment: I found a module that does exactly what I need
http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role

After enabling the module, just edit the link you want and at the bottom under "restrict item visibility"


(I couldn't answer my own question for another 6 hours and I didn't want anyone wasting their time, so I posted it as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

`hook_perm()` was renamed to [`hook_permission()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in Drupal 7, and there's a bit of a mismatch between `view mylink` that you define and `view joblist` that you declare as a permission.

You could change your code to look more like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mylink'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_mylink',
    'access arguments' => array('view mylink'),
    'title' => 'My Link',
    'description' => 'My Link',
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_permission() {
  return array(
    'view mylink' => array(
      'Title' => 'View My Link'
    )
  );
}
```

After you clear Drupal's cache navigate to `admin/people/permissions` and assign your new permission to the role you want to be able to access the page you define in `hook_menu()`.

Once you've done that users with that role will be able to access the page :)

Comment: I can still see the menu item when the user is not authorized.

Comment: I added an image of what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following module: [Menu Item Visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility), it does exactly what you need.